# IBM ILE RPG - Clear time fields

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

How can I clear (reset) a field defined as type `TIME`?

I have already tried to `MOVEL *BLANKS` or `Z-ADD *ZEROS`, but I always get an error. When using `*ZEROS` the compiler tells me that the field is  not numeric. While using `MOVEL *BLANKS` I get an error that factor 2 is invalid for this operation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't move blanks or zeros to a time field -- you have to move a time. I personally would just use the CLEAR operand, or you could use EVAL along with the %TIME BIF. Either of the 2 statements below would accomplish this task.

```
 D  TIME           S               T

 C                   CLEAR                   TIME

 C                   EVAL      TIME = %TIME('00000000')
```

Comment: already tried `CLEAR` but used it wrong...now it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have 3 options:

```
      /free
       timeField = *loval;
       clear timeField;
       reset timeField;
      /end-free
```

You can do it in fixed format as well, but seeing that you're referring to RPGLE I would recommend you start moving away from fixed format.

#### Edit

The OP uses fixed format so here is the reference to the opt-code documentation: [CLEAR](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/iseries/v5r2/ic2924/books/c0924514583.htm)

So just put the time variable in the **result field** and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't use free RPG. nevertheless I will take a try to use it.